# Auto insert TODO statistics to a parent heading

Tags: org-mode

Example, given a sub-heading if I issue `org-todo` on `task 1`

```
** my tasks
*** task 1
```

How can I get the statistics to auto insert?

```
** [0/1] my tasks
*** TODO task 1
```

Comment: You have to put the cookie at the end of the heading like this: `** my tasks [/]`. Do `M-: (info "(org)Breaking down tasks")` for more info.

Comment: I was wrong: you can leave the cookie where it is (as long as it's after any TODO keyword). But you should read the section I pointed to.

Comment: Is there a way to `[/]` to add to the parent heading without me having to do it?

Comment: No - not out of the box. But it's a one time operation to add that to a given headline. All that Org mode provides is the counting and the automatic update of the cookie.

Comment: BTW, what do you mean by "without me having to do it"? Do you want the cookie on *every* headline? Every top-level headline? Or do you want perhaps a simple keybinding to a function that does it so it's under your control? All of those are possible to some extent or another (not worth the hassle IMO, but YMMV).